# Knowing the time number of times print function is called here and how can I express this sudo code in a summation form

Tags: summation

```
for i from 1 to n do

    for j from 2 to n*n do
        print ‘Q’
    end do
    print newline

end do
```

For the double for loop, which is a pseudocode I am confused as how to write this in a sigma notation format (sum format) on how many times the print subroutine is called. Kindly assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Notation:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\sum\limits_{j=2}^{n^2}1\right)$$

---

The `print` subroutine is invoked $n+n(n^2-1)=n^3$ times.

Comment: You need to include the print newline call in your sum also: $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\sum\limits_{j=2}^{n^2}1\right)$$

Comment: @SteveKass: Oh, right... I didn't see it due to the rather poor formatting of the question.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the formatting so it’s clearer to everyone.

Comment: @barakmanos Could you please explain how you came about 1. I can see that you said the print subroutine is called n^3 times but is that not meant to be plugged into the sum equation instead of 1? Thanks.

Comment: @ubaa67: What "$1$"???